# 3D exporting and Qgis2threejs plugin

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs

I have a `.shp`-file of some buildings with a sheet in an attribute table of their height. I want to extrude them using a Qgis2threejs plugin, but since a sheet of height is shown as a type of `QString`, the plugin can't recognize it and the buildings can't be extruded.

I have tried to export a database as a `.csv`-file, but the Excel is locked and it can't be modified.

Any alternative approaches?

Comment: Perhaps, these references can inspire you, check [How can I change an attribute table field type from string to double in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141013/how-can-i-change-an-attribute-table-field-type-from-string-to-double-in-qgis), [Changing data type in attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34343/changing-data-type-in-attribute-table-in-qgis), [How to change the type of a column of an attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247373/how-to-change-the-type-of-a-column-of-an-attribute-table-in-qgis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the heights are in a column of the attributes table, but stored as `QString` type, you can convert them in a new numeric type column.

- Add a new field with the *Decimal number (real)* type and the desired length and precision in the attribute table.
- Populate that field in the *Field Calculator* with the expression:

`to_real("height")`

Where `"height"` is the name of the string type field.